# Scala accept only String or Int generic case class in List

Tags: java, scala

I have a case class defined as below

```
case class ChooseBoxData[T](index:T, text:String)
```

Is it possible to declare a List so that the list only accept type of ChooseBoxData[String] and ChooseBoxData[Int]?

What I expected is something like:

```
val specialList:List[some type declaration] = List(
  ChooseBoxData[String]("some string","some string"),/* allow, because is ChooseBoxData[String]*/
  ChooseBoxData[Int](12,"some string"), /* also allow, because is ChooseBoxData[Int]*/
  ChooseBoxData[Boolean](true,"some string")/* not allow type other than ChooseBoxData[String] or ChooseBoxData[Int]*/
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
trait AllowableBoxData  
object AllowableBoxData {
private of[T](cbd: ChooseBoxData[T]) = new ChooseBoxData(cbd.index, cbd.text) 
    with AllowableBoxData
  implicit def ofInt(cbd: ChooseBoxData[Int]) = of(cbd)
  implicit def ofString(cbd: ChooseBoxData[String]) = of(cbd)
}
```

Now you can do things like

```
val list: List[ChooseBoxData[_] with AllowableBoxData] = List(ChooseBoxData("foo", "bar"), ChooseBoxData(0, "baz")
```

But not `val list: List[AllowableBoxData] = List(ChooseBoxData(false, "baz"))`

Also, if you were looking to declare a function argument rather than just a variable, there would be a bit more elegant solution:

```
trait CanUse[T]
implicit case object CanUseInt extends CanUse[Int]
implicit case object CanUseString extends CanUse[String]

def foo[T : CanUse](bar: List[ChooseBoxData[T]])
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be `def`s for the methods inside the object definition?

Comment: Also, how to extract `ChooseBoxData`s from the resulting list?

Comment: Yeah, missed the `def`s, sorry,, 
Not sure what you mean by "how to extract ..." there a few ways, like `list.head` or `list.last` or `list(123)` etc ...

Comment: I can't do `list.head.index` or `list.head.text` though

Comment: @jrook why not?

Comment: I am getting this error: `Error: value index is not a member of A$A1160.this.AllowableBoxData...`.

Comment: @jrook ah, yeah ... You need to declare it as `List[ChooseBoxData[_] with AllowableBoxData]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

First, we create the following Algebraic Data Types (ADT):

```
sealed trait StringInt

case class Stringy(s : String) extends StringInt
case class Inty(s : Int) extends StringInt
```

And define `ChoooseBoxData` as follows:

```
case class ChooseBoxData(index : StringInt, text : String)
```

Then we define the following implicts to convert `Int` and `String` in the scope to the defined ADT:

```
object CBImplicits {
  implicit def conv(u : String) = Stringy(u)
  implicit def conv2(u : Int) = Inty(u)
}
```

Now, we can enforce the requirement in the question. Here is an example:

```
import CBImplicits._

val list = List(ChooseBoxData("str", "text"),
ChooseBoxData(1, "text"),
ChooseBoxData(true, "text"))
```

Trying to run the above, the compiler will complain about type mismatch. But this will compile and run:

```
List(
  ChooseBoxData("str", "text"),
  ChooseBoxData(1, "text"),
  ChooseBoxData(12, "text2"))
```

which results in:

```
a: List[ChooseBoxData] = 
List(ChooseBoxData(Stringy(str),text), ChooseBoxData(Inty(1),text), ChooseBoxData(Inty(12),text2))
```

This preserves `index` type information (wrapped in `StringInt` supertype of course) which later can be easily extracted using pattern matching for individual elements.

It is easy to remove the wrapper for all elements too, but it will result in the `index` type to become `Any` which is what we would expect because `Any` is the lowest common ancestor for both `String` and `Int` in Scala's class hierarchy.

**EDIT: A Solution Using [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)**

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.typeable._

case class ChooseBoxData[T](index : T, text : String)

val a = ChooseBoxData(1, "txt")
val b = ChooseBoxData("str", "txt")
val c = ChooseBoxData(true, "txt")
val list = List(a, b, c)

val `ChooseBoxData[Int]` = TypeCase[ChooseBoxData[Int]]
val `ChooseBoxData[String]` = TypeCase[ChooseBoxData[String]]

val res = list.map {
  case `ChooseBoxData[Int]`(u) => u
  case `ChooseBoxData[String]`(u) => u
  case _ => None
}
//result
res: List[Product with Serializable] = List(ChooseBoxData(1,txt), ChooseBoxData(str,txt), None)
```

So it allows compilation, but will replace invalid instances with `None` (which then can be used to throw a runtime error if desired), or you can directly filter the instances you want using:

```
list.flatMap(x => x.cast[ChooseBoxData[Int]])
//results in:
List[ChooseBoxData[Int]] = List(ChooseBoxData(1,txt))
```

Comment: Well... at least the scala console had no issues with `val list = List(ChooseBoxData("str", "text"),
ChooseBoxData(1, "text"),
ChooseBoxData(true, "text"))`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, sorry, I had forgotten to add how I define the case class. Now it should be clear. `index` can only be `StringInt` which is ultimately either a String or Int.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, looks like the first solution will not allow me declare ChooseBoxData[Boolean] anymore, but I will still need it in other class,

If possible I don't wish using filter, but currently it's looks like the best solution for me

Comment: @jialeko, the solution using shapeless gives back `None` for boolean index. So it can be used to throw a run time exception if that works. For the solution using ADT, I guess you can extend the base trait in different classes to allow different rules in different places.

Comment: @jialeko, for example, if you comment out the last line in the `map` function (`case _ => None`), you will get a match error.

Answer (score 0):

You can build extra constraint on top of your case class.

```
import language.implicitConversions

case class ChooseBoxData[T](index:T, text:String)

trait MySpecialConstraint[T] {
  def get: ChooseBoxData[T]
}

implicit def liftWithMySpecialConstraintString(cbd: ChooseBoxData[String]) =
  new MySpecialConstraint[String] {
    def get = cbd
  }

implicit def liftWithMySpecialConstraintInt(cbd: ChooseBoxData[Int]) =
  new MySpecialConstraint[Int] {
    def get = cbd
  }


// Now we can just use this constraint for out list 
val l1: List[MySpecialConstraint[_]] = List(ChooseBoxData("A1", "B1"), ChooseBoxData(2, "B2"))
```

Comment: Could you explain how can the user get a `ChooseBoxData(Int, String)` or a `ChooseBoxData(String, String)` from the final list?

Comment: pattern-matching can help with that. I don't prefer changing the `case class` itself for this purpose, because it may be something which is not controlled by OP.

Comment: I tried `l1(0).get.index` and I am getting: `res0 :Any = A1`

Comment: `val ChooseBoxData(index: String, text) = l1(0).get`

Comment: I guess it is worth noting that this works when the type to work with is `MySpecialConstraint`. Still, something like `List(ChooseBoxData[Double](1.3, "txt"))` compiles and runs.

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you do it like this:

```
object solution extends App {

  case class ChooseBoxData[T](index: T, text: String) extends GenericType[T]

  trait GenericType[T] {
    def getType(index: T, text: String): ChooseBoxData[T] = ChooseBoxData[T](index, text)
  }

  val specialList = List(
    ChooseBoxData[String]("some string", "some string"),
    ChooseBoxData[Int](12, "some string"), 
    ChooseBoxData[Boolean](true, "some string")
  )

  println(specialList)
}

//output: List(ChooseBoxData(some string,some string), ChooseBoxData(12,some string), ChooseBoxData(true,some string))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I'm a bit confuse on your solution.... can you further explain how it not allow ChooseBoxData[Boolean] in the list?

Comment: actually it does allow! Boolean too. i will update the answer to meet your requirement